# How can I manually use gradients with PyTorch optimizers instead of autograd?

Tags: pytorch, torch, autograd

Autograd doesn't seem to be working reliably for a dataset I'm currently working with and I would like to use manually computed gradients with the Torch's SGD optimizer. I've written code to explicitly compute gradients, so I know the gradients but I don't know how to use these instead of Torch's autograd gradients.
In particular, I want to do the following:

```
optimizer = torch.SGD([X], lr)
for epoch in epochs:
   loss = my_function(X)
   gradients = compute_gradients_using_my_function(X,loss)
   optimizer.apply_grads([X], gradients)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear to me. For a better sense of understanding what is going on under the hood in autograd, check this rep https://github.com/karpathy/micrograd. This is a simple version of autograd, written by Andrej Karpathy.

Comment: I don't want to use autograd. I want to use my own function, which can compute the gradient at each iterate.

Comment: @user3131493 So, use computed gradients ruled by the SGD equation. Remember, you have to use w.data to update a parameter's value.

Comment: What do you mean by this?